# Magento 2 POST Request Return 302 Redirect

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, ajax, jquery

I have Image Manager from Ves Base Widget, the issue is when the user tried to upload the image from his computer to the image manager, so that means the request called from Javascript and returned with Status code 302.

[image]